# Setting Time Limit on specific task with celery

Tags: celery, celeryd

I have a task in Celery that could potentially run for 10,000 seconds while operating normally.  However all the rest of my tasks should be done in less than one second.  How can I set a time limit for the intentionally long running task without changing the time limit on the short running tasks?

Answer (score 91):

You can set task time limits ([hard](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#Task.time_limit) and/or [soft](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#Task.soft_time_limit)) either while defining a task or while calling.

```py
from celery.exceptions import SoftTimeLimitExceeded

@celery.task(time_limit=20)
def mytask():
    try:
        return do_work()
    except SoftTimeLimitExceeded:
        cleanup_in_a_hurry()
```

or

```py
mytask.apply_async(args=[], kwargs={}, time_limit=30, soft_time_limit=10)
```

Comment: note that the timeout/soft_timeout arguments to apply_async is only available in the development version of celery (master branch, the future version 3.1)

Comment: You can also set time-limits for a task in configuration by using: `CELERY_ANNOTATIONS = {'module.mytask': {'time_limit': 20.0}}`

Comment: For celery versions 3.1.x it looks like the `timeout/soft_timeout` arguments to `apply_async` have also been changed to `time_limit/soft_time_limit`. The relevant change was introduced here - https://github.com/celery/celery/commit/be6cef2e441e5ecf5857aeb77bd885f06128b9c9

Comment: adding to @sanchitarora comment, a link from 3.1.20 docs - http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#Task.soft_time_limit

Answer (score 14):

This is an example with decorator for an specific Task and Celery 3.1.23 using **soft_time_limit**=10000

```
@task(bind=True, default_retry_delay=30, max_retries=3, soft_time_limit=10000)
def process_task(self, task_instance):
   """Task processing."""
        pass
```

Comment: You can also assign `time_limit` together like `@task(soft_time_limit=10, time_limit=15)`