# Link celery tasks on TimeLimitExceeded or Failure

Tags: celery, celery-task

- '**worker_collect**' is the celery package.

  - All the tasks are routing into the same queue.
  - I'm executing 2 tasks.
  - The task 'collect_data' is calling a task '**do_request**'.
  - I put a **sleep(5)** in order to force the timeout.
  - When the task '**do_request**' timeout of fail I'm trying to call the task '**fetch_result**'

The function '**fetch_result**' is empty but afterwards it should get the result of the task '**do_request**'.

**My question :**

Where do I have to catch the exception raised '**TimeLimitExceeded**' in order to call the function '**fetch_result**' ?

**Here is the code :**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from time import sleep
from worker_collect.celery import app
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger
from celery.exceptions import TimeLimitExceeded


@app.task(time_limit=3 , max_retries=None)
def fetch_result():

    logger = get_task_logger(__name__)
    logger.info('-------------------')
    logger.info('----- FETCH -------')
    logger.info('-------------------')
    logger.info('-------------------')

@app.task(time_limit=3 , max_retries=None)
def do_request():

    logger = get_task_logger(__name__)
    logger.info('---------------------')
    logger.info('----- DO REQUEST ----')
    logger.info('---------------------')
    logger.info('---------------------')
    sleep(5)
    return 'do_request DONE'

@app.task(time_limit=8 , max_retries=None)
def collect_data():

    logger = get_task_logger(__name__)
    logger.info('---------------------')
    logger.info('-----COLLECT DATA----')
    logger.info('---------------------')

    do_request.apply_async(link=fetch_result.s(), link_error=fetch_result.s())

    logger.info('---------------------')
    logger.info('--END COLLECT DATA---')
    logger.info('---------------------')
```

**Here are the celery logs**

```
[2015-02-13 15:18:08,275: INFO/Beat] beat: Starting...
[2015-02-13 15:18:08,301: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//
[2015-02-13 15:18:08,315: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2015-02-13 15:18:09,328: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2015-02-13 15:18:09,366: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@collector ready.
[2015-02-13 15:18:09,416: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: worker_collect.tasks.collect_data[1df333f3-cc34-4d10-ad1b-181432bf2283]
[2015-02-13 15:18:09,419: INFO/Worker-5] worker_collect.tasks.collect_data[1df333f3-cc34-4d10-ad1b-181432bf2283]: ---------------------
[2015-02-13 15:18:09,420: INFO/Worker-5] worker_collect.tasks.collect_data[1df333f3-cc34-4d10-ad1b-181432bf2283]: -----COLLECT DATA----
[2015-02-13 15:18:09,421: INFO/Worker-5] worker_collect.tasks.collect_data[1df333f3-cc34-4d10-ad1b-181432bf2283]: ---------------------
[2015-02-13 15:18:09,469: INFO/Worker-5] worker_collect.tasks.collect_data[1df333f3-cc34-4d10-ad1b-181432bf2283]: ---------------------
[2015-02-13 15:18:09,470: INFO/Worker-5] worker_collect.tasks.collect_data[1df333f3-cc34-4d10-ad1b-181432bf2283]: --END COLLECT DATA---
[2015-02-13 15:18:09,470: INFO/Worker-5] worker_collect.tasks.collect_data[1df333f3-cc34-4d10-ad1b-181432bf2283]: ---------------------
[2015-02-13 15:18:09,470: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: worker_collect.tasks.do_request[333e3002-c014-416f-a85a-ca839bd5376c]
[2015-02-13 15:18:09,472: INFO/Worker-2] worker_collect.tasks.do_request[333e3002-c014-416f-a85a-ca839bd5376c]: ---------------------
[2015-02-13 15:18:09,472: INFO/Worker-2] worker_collect.tasks.do_request[333e3002-c014-416f-a85a-ca839bd5376c]: ----- DO REQUEST ----
[2015-02-13 15:18:09,472: INFO/Worker-2] worker_collect.tasks.do_request[333e3002-c014-416f-a85a-ca839bd5376c]: ---------------------
[2015-02-13 15:18:09,473: INFO/Worker-2] worker_collect.tasks.do_request[333e3002-c014-416f-a85a-ca839bd5376c]: ---------------------
[2015-02-13 15:18:09,475: INFO/MainProcess] Task worker_collect.tasks.collect_data[1df333f3-cc34-4d10-ad1b-181432bf2283] succeeded in 0.0564397389971s: None
[2015-02-13 15:18:12,478: ERROR/MainProcess] Task worker_collect.tasks.do_request[333e3002-c014-416f-a85a-ca839bd5376c] raised unexpected: TimeLimitExceeded(3,)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bschom/celery_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/billiard/pool.py", line 639, in on_hard_timeout
    raise TimeLimitExceeded(job._timeout)
TimeLimitExceeded: TimeLimitExceeded(3,)
[2015-02-13 15:18:12,479: ERROR/MainProcess] Hard time limit (3s) exceeded for worker_collect.tasks.do_request[333e3002-c014-416f-a85a-ca839bd5376c]
[2015-02-13 15:18:12,587: ERROR/MainProcess] Process 'Worker-2' pid:14159 exited with 'signal 9 (SIGKILL)'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11672179/setting-time-limit-on-specific-task-with-celery