# How to set a timeout to interrupt the calling method in python?

Tags: python, django

I want to set a timeout in the view, if the code execution in the view exceeds the timeout

```
# urls.py
url(r'^test-api/$', test_api_view)

# views.py
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.response import Response

def test_api_view(request):
       timeout=10
      data = someMethod() 
   if xxx: # Call some_method() for more than 10 seconds, and the method call may not end   
        return Response({"error": "Timeout"})
    else:
        return Response(data)
```

Comment: Several options here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492519/timeout-on-a-function-call

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `celery`. You can find a working example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11672179/setting-time-limit-on-specific-task-with-celery).

idea:

```
# views.py
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.response import Response
from celery.exceptions import SoftTimeLimitExceeded

from my_functions import my_function

def test_api_view(request):
    try:
        data = my_function()
    except SoftTimeLimitExceeded:
        return Response({"error": "Timeout"})
    else:
        return Response(data)
```

```
@celery.task(time_limit=20)
def mytask():
    some_method()  # method to do thing
```