# How to give dynamic soft_time_limit for celery task

Tags: python-3.x, celery

Need to add the dynamic **soft_time_limit** for my task. The task should be executed based on dynamic soft_time_limit. I should not mention a limit for this execution. Is there any way to define this?

```
@APP.task(acks_late=True, soft_time_limit=10000, trail=True, bind=True)
def execute_fun(self, data):
    try:
        do_work()
    except Exception as error:
        print('---error---', error)
```

Here in the above function, I don't want to define the **soft_time_limit**, It should take it as a dynamic time limit. How should I achieve this?

Comment: I do not think it is possible. I hope I am wrong.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/11678102/5832540

Comment: @TomášLinhart in this also they have mentioned soft_time_limit=10000, so we don't want this hardcoded 10000 value. It should take a dynamic time limit according to the task.

Comment: @Hushen The most upvoted answer mentions that you can pass the value as an argument to `apply_async`, thus specifying it dynamically.

Comment: mytask.apply_async(args=[], kwargs={}, time_limit=30, soft_time_limit=10)
what happen when my task is not completed in 10 seconds?. anyhow I have mentioned as parameter soft_time_limit=10